# Iterating over an RDD Iterable in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, key-pair, java-pair-rdd

So I am new to Scala and just starting to work with RDDs and functional Scala operations.

I am trying to iterate over the values of my Pair RDDs and return `Var1` with the average of the values stored in `Var2` by applying the defined `average`function so that the final return is a unique list of Var1 with a single `AvgVar2` associated with each one. I am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to iterate over the values.

*edit: I have the following type declarations:

```
case class ID: Int,  Var1: Int, Var2: Int extends Serializable
```

I have the following function:

```
  def foo(rdds: RDD[(ID, Iterable[(Var1, Var2)])]): RDD[(Var1, AvgVar2)] = {

    def average(as: Array[Var2]): AvgVar2 = {
       var sum = 0.0
       var i = 0.0
       while (i < as.length) {
           sum += Var2.val
           i += 1
      }
      sum/i
    }

    //My attempt at Scala
    rdds.map(x=> ((x._1),x._2)).groupByKey().map(x=>average(x._1)).collect()
}
```

My attempt at Scala is trying to do the following:

1. split the RDD pair Iterable into key-value pairs of `Var1-Var2`.
2. Group by the key of `Var1` and create an array of associated `Var2`.
3. Apply my `average` function to each array of `Var2`
4. Return the `AvgVar2` with the associated `Var1` as a collection of RDDs

*Edit:

Some sample input data for `rdds`:

```
//RDD[(ID,Iterable[(Var1,Var2)...])]
RDD[(1,[(1,3),(1,12),(1,6)])],
RDD[(2,[(2,5),(2,7)])]
```

Some sample output data:

```
//RDD[(Var1, AvgVar2)]
RDD[(1,7),(2,6)]
```

*Edit: Line of working scala code:

```
rdd.map(x => (x._2.map(it => it._1).asInstanceOf[Var1], average(x._2.map(it => it._2).toArray)))
```

Comment: Is there are any specific reason you decided to use RDD instead of DataFrames?

Comment: Can you provide a sample input & output?. Can same `Var1` value occur in different `ID` ?

Comment: @vdep, each unique `Var1` value can only be associated with a single ID, but I want to drop the ID in the return RDD. I have added in sample input and output data in my edit that I hope clarifies the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering `ID` = `Var1`, a simple `.map()` will solve it:

```
def foo(rdds: RDD[(Int, Iterable[(Int, Int)])]): RDD[(Int, Double)] = {

  def average(as: Iterable[(Int, Int)]): Double = {
    as.map(_._2).reduce(_+_)/as.size.toDouble
  }

  rdds.map(x => (x._1, average(x._2)))
}
```

Output:

```
val input = sc.parallelize(List((1,Iterable((1,3),(1,12),(1,6))), (2, Iterable((2,5),(2,7)))))

scala> foo(input).collect
res0: Array[(Int, Double)] = Array((1,7.0), (2,6.0))
```

EDITED: (`average()` with same signature):

```
def foo(rdds: RDD[(Int, Iterable[(Int, Int)])]): RDD[(Int, Double)] = {

  def average(as: Array[Int]): Double = {
    as.reduce(_+_)/as.size.toDouble
  }

  rdds.map(x => (x._1, average(x._2.map(tuple => tuple._2).toArray)))
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, but would it be possible for you to do without changing the form of the `average` function? I want to understand how to create an array from the various `Var2` so I can apply any function of signature `average(as: Array[Var2])` to an RDD in the given form. Additionally, while the `ID == Var1`, they are different object types so that would cause the function to throw an error. I'll admit this is for a homework assignment so I need the types to match exactly.

Comment: @EliSquared  edited the answer. I am Not sure what do you mean by: " ID == Var1, they are different object types so that would cause the function to throw an error"

Comment: I mean that `ID` and `Var1` are each defined classes (see edit above the function). Now the only error I am having is on the `x._1` which returns an `ID`, when I need it to return the first element of the Iterable (`Var1`). I am now trying something like this: `rdds.map(x => (x._2.map(it=> it._1), average(x._2.map(tuple => tuple._2).toArray)))`, to try and select the first element of the iterable, but am still getting a type error.

Comment: I actually got it to work, I just had to added in: `.asInstanceOf[Var1]` after `(x._2.map(it=> it._1)` => `(x._2.map(it=> it._1).asInstanceOf[Var1]`. See fully working code line above. That being said if you can optimize for efficiency or readability, I would be interested.